# Fork concept, dont quite grasp how fork works

Tags: c, fork, concept

I try to draw out the process according to the code but I really need some explanation in why, here is the question:

```
B() {
     pid_t pid;
     if ((pid = fork()) != 0)
         waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
     printf("2");
     if(fork() ==0)
       { printf("3"); exit(0); }
     printf("5");
     exit(0);
}

Which one are illegals output?
232553, 235325, 232355, 235253, 252533...
```

This is the process I draw out according to the code and my understanding of fork.

```
            ___3 (exit so no more here)
           |
      __2__|___5 (I guess 5 should be here)
     |          |        
     |          |
 ____|____(wait)|(start again since printf 3 process end)
```

So I'm stuck right there... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't expect to see the output in any particular order ... besides "2" being first

Comment: That is true, what I mean though, is how the rest play out? The drawing is my interpretation of the code and it is not finish. What I want to ask though, is that what else would appear after wait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, there are two forks.  Here is control flow, from left to right, with parents on top and children on the bottom:

```
    +-- B ---- waitpid() --+                  +-- "5" -- E
    |                      |                  |
A --+ fork()               +-- C -- "2" -- D -+ fork()
    |                      |                  |
    +----------------------+                  +-- "3" -- F
```

So, what do we know?

- "2", "5", and "3" each appear twice (90 possibilities)
- No prefix may contain more "3" than "2" (30 possibilities)
- No prefix may contain more "5" than "2" (16 possibilities)
- The second "2" must be preceded by the first "5" (7 possibilities)

The 7 possibilities are:

```
2,3,5,2,3,5
2,3,5,2,5,3
2,5,2,3,3,5
2,5,2,3,5,3
2,5,2,5,3,3
2,5,3,2,3,5
2,5,3,2,5,3
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be the program path (`x` denotes termination):

```
---+--(wait)-2-+-5-x
   |           |
   +-2-+-5-x   +-3-x
       |   
       +-*3-x
```

After the first `fork`, the parent waits for the child to finish. But in case of second `fork`, it does not wait. So, * marked 3 can be printed anywhere after first 2. The order of printing 5 and 3 after second `fork` also can not be determined. Therefore, the possible outputs are:

25235*3
25253*3
2523*35
2525*33
252*335
252*353
25*3235
25*3253
2*35235
2*35253

Answer (score 1):

Since the order of execution with *fork()* is not deterministic, you can only expect that each integer (i.e., 2, 3 and 5) will be printed twice. The order depends on how the scheduler chooses to schedule the processes.

You can force a particular  order using *sleep* commands or some other synchronization primitive.

Answer (score 1):

The first `fork()` splits the process into 2 parts (parent and child). The parent waits and the child prints 2.

Then the child does `fork()`; and then child prints 5 and exits (which allows the parent to start running again) while the child's child (grandchild?) prints 3. This can happen in any order.

The parent continues and prints 2 (this may happen before or after the grandchild prints 3; but after the now terminated child printed 5).

Then the parent does `fork()`; and the parent prints 5 and it's second child prints 2 (which can happen in any order, and may happen before the grandchild prints 5).

Answer (score 0):

The first fork creates a child and waits for it. So the main program only goes on running as soon as the first child exits.

So the first output is "the child's" `2`.
Then a `3` and a `5` is printed, in any order. Only after the `3` or the `5` the second `2` can occur, and then the second `3` and/or `5`.

So

```
232553 is ok
235325 is not ok, as the 2nd 3 comes before the 2nd 2
232355 is ok
235253 is ok
252533 is ok
```